# Replacing {text} in .txt or array with different text

Tags: c#

Consider having the following strings in a .txt file

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.2
127.0.0.3
```

Or in an array:

```
{"127.0.0.1","127.0.0.2","127.0.0.3"}
```

And consider having the following strings into a different .txt file:

```
curl -sS -L https://github.com/vulmon/Vulmap/archive/master.tar.gz -o vulmap.tgz && echo y | sshpass -p 'ubuntu' scp -q ./vulmap.tgz ubuntu@192.168.74.133: && echo y | sshpass -p '{password}' ssh {username}@{ip} "mkdir -p ~/tmp-vulmap && cd ~/tmp-vulmap && tar -xzf ../vulmap.tgz && rm ../vulmap.tgz && cd ./Vulmap-master/Vulmap-Linux && python3 vulmap-linux.py"
```

```
curl -sS -L https://github.com/D0cT0r-inf0s3c/Praus/archive/master.tar.gz -o praus.tgz && echo y | sshpass -p 'ubuntu' scp -q ./praus.tgz ubuntu@192.168.74.133: && echo y | sshpass -p '{password}' ssh {username}@{ip} "mkdir -p ~/tmp-praus && cd ~/tmp-praus && tar -xzf ../praus.tgz && rm ../praus.tgz && cd ./Praus-master && (echo; echo 2; echo 1; echo 8; echo; echo 3; echo; echo 1;) | sudo bash praus.sh"
```

```
curl -L https://github.com/speed47/spectre-meltdown-checker/archive/master.tar.gz -o spectre-meltdown-checker.tgz && sshpass -p '{password}' scp -q ./spectre-meltdown-checker.tgz {username}@{ip}: && sshpass -p '{password}' ssh {username}@{password} "mkdir -p ~/tmp-BeRoot && cd ~/tmp-spectre-meltdown-checker && tar -xzf ../spectre-meltdown-checker.tgz && rm ../spectre-meltdown-checker.tgz && cd ./spectre-meltdown-checker-master && ./spectre-meltdown-checker.sh"
```

Is there a possibility that I can replace the strings **{ip}** with the IP's? For the username and password an argument by user input will be parsed through. If the **{ip}** will work then I will find out those two as well.

Conditions:

- The code will be ran parallel so it might be handy to loop through the first .txt file and save those in a variable if necessary.

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: Do some research around String.Format and String Manipulation in C#.

Comment: Those strings look like shell scripts, how are you executing them? Why not try to process variables in the shell scripts? Why are you asking about c#? Do you really want to re-download the checker binary every time you use it? Can you solve the problem with xargs?

Comment: @zaitsman : Well honestly I tried to look up some searchs on the internet, but I haven't found what I want. Either I do not ask the question correctly, or the information is not there.

Comment: @Dev : I will do, I will check if that will help me. I have another question. Do you happen to know if String Manipulation works when accessing .txt files, else I do have to read all lines first of 2 specific text files before saving them into an array and then execute each command attached to it. I do have a similar situation where IP addresses are loaded from memory into an method that executes multiple commands. So that would not be the problem.

Comment: @Jeremy Lakeman : The scripts will be changed a bit so the plink will be execute and download all packages on the host so no .zip files will be on the on where the actual script is executed. The program is written in C#, so that is why I ask a C# related question. Proper validation if the program is there will be done later.

Comment: You will be able to replace the dynamic part of your string and then execute the final string.

Comment: If you have an example that would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to this issue:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string replace = @"{ip}";
        //Hosts & programs
        string whosts = @"/hosts/windows.txt";
        string lhosts = @"/hosts/linux.txt";
        string defaultprofile = "programs.config";
        //IP Locations
        string llocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + lhosts;
        string wlocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + whosts;
        //string[] ips = { "127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.2", "127.0.0.3", "127.0.0.4", "127.0.0.5", "127.0.0.6", "127.0.0.7", "127.0.0.8", "127.0.0.9", "127.0.0.10", "127.0.0.0" };
        //Read winips and linips
        List<string> winhosts = File.ReadAllLines(wlocation).ToList();
        List<string> linhosts = File.ReadAllLines(wlocation).ToList();
        ParallelOptions? options = new() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount, CancellationToken = CancellationToken.None };
        //Check if windows.txt contains any hosts
        if (winhosts.Any())
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"/example/" + defaultprofile);
            List<string> winprograms = lines.SkipWhile(x => x != "WINVULNSCAN:")  // skips everything before 
            .Skip(1)                           // and <rs:data> itself
            .TakeWhile(x => x != "LINVULNSCAN:") // and take up to </rs:data>
            .ToList(); //Converts it to a List
            Parallel.ForEach(winhosts, host =>
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(winprograms, line =>
                {
                    string? result = line.Replace(replace, host);
                    Console.WriteLine(result + Environment.NewLine);
                });
            });
        }
        //check if linux.txt contains any hosts
        if (linhosts.Any())
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"/example/" + defaultprofile);
            List<string> linprograms = lines.SkipWhile(x => x != "LINVULNSCAN:")  // skips everything before 
            .Skip(1)                           // and <rs:data> itself
            .TakeWhile(x => x != "OTHERVULNSCAN:") // and take up to </rs:data>
            .ToList(); //Converts it to a List
            Parallel.ForEach(linhosts, host =>
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(linprograms, line =>
                {
                    string? result = line.Replace(replace, host);
                    Console.WriteLine(result + Environment.NewLine);
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is a self-answer, but content here is supposed to help future users as well. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: Will do :) @Chris